# How would I modify this code so that it can dynamically allocate based on a count?

Tags: c, unix

I'm new to C and I made this file sorter that basically traverses through a directory and prints out a sorted list of all the files in it based on size.

```
#define MAXFILE 10000

struct fileList
{
    char fName[256];
    unsigned int fileSize;
};

void sorter...
//Sorts files

void rec_tav(char *path, struct fileList f_arr[MAXFILE])
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat sb;
    char newPath[256];
    
    dir = opendir(path);
    if(!dir){
        return;
    }
    
    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(ent->d_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") == 0)
            continue;
        strcpy(newPath,path);
        strcat(newPath,"/");
        strcat(newPath,ent->d_name);
        stat(newPath, &sb);
        if((S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) != 0 && (stat(newPath,&sb))==0){
            strcpy(f_arr[fileCount].fName,newPath);
            f_arr[fileCount].fileSize = sb.st_size;
            fileCount++;
        }
            
        rec_tav(newPath,f_arr);
        }
            
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    struct fileList file_array[MAXFILE];
    rec_tav(argv[1],file_array);
    sorter(file_array);
    for(int i = 0; i < fileCount;i++)
        printf("%d\t%s\n", file_array[i].fileSize,file_array[i].fName);
}
```

It works expect that I have to define a maximum file count. How can I alter it so that it works dynamically based on the file count? Im assuming that an array of struct wont work anymore but I dont know what I should use instead.

Comment: Look into the POSIX [`scandir(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) function.

Comment: Also: `snprintf(newPath, sizeof newPath, "%s/%s", path, ent->d_name);` instead of that `strcpy()`/multiple `strcat()` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

So the idiomatic way would be to change the signature of you function to something like `int rec_tav(char *path, fileList **tab);` so the return value would be the number of entries, and *tab would be the array of entries.
Inside the function, you might have code like this where you add one entry:

```
   fileList *temp;
   temp = realloc(*tab, (fileCount+1) * sizeof *temp);
   if (temp == NULL) {
         free(*tab);
         return -1;
   }
   *tab = temp;
   strcpy((*tab)[fileCount].fName,newPath);
   (*tab)[fileCount].fileSize = sb.st_size;
   fileCount++;
```

Although you might want to grow it by chunks, then shrink it back at the end.

Your recursive step only adds a small problem, and since you weren't dealing with it anyways, we can just add a small bit here:

```
  int n;
  fileList *newtab = NULL;
  n = rec_tav(path, &newtab);
  if (n > 0) {
       fileList *temp;
       temp = realloc(*tab, (n+fileCount) * sizeof *temp);
       if (temp == NULL) {
             free(*tab);
             free(newtab);
             return -1;
       }
       memcpy(temp + fileCount, newtab, n*sizeof *temp);
       *tab = temp;
       free(newtab);
       fileCount += n;
 }
```